# Uploading xgboost to azure machine learning: %1 is not a valid Win32 application\r\nProcess returned with non-zero exit code 1

Tags: python, azure, python-3.5, azure-machine-learning-service

I've tried to upload the xgboost python library to Azure ML, however it claim that my library is not a Win32 application.
I've made sure to install the 32 bit version of the package and i'm running conda 32 bit as well.
I downloaded the library from:
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#xgboost
and chose the 32 bit python 3.5 version.
Python installation as below.
[image: python installation]

This is the error I get returned azure ml error
[image: azure ml error]

Here is my installation of anaconda conda installation
[image: conda installation]

Can anyone see where I went wrong?

Best Regards

EDIT:
Yes I followed the document and uploaded a zip file containing the wheel file. When I run the following it works just fine:
"import pip" and   "pip.main(['install', './Script Bundle/xgboost-0.6-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl'])"
But when I add "import xgboost" I get this error.[Import error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/coYnH.jpg)

Comment: Please merge your description via edit, not as answers.

Comment: How did you upload `xgboost` wheel file to Azure ML? Did you follow the document(https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/cdb56f95-7f4c-404d-bde7-5bb972e6f232/#Technical Notes) to upload it as a zip file?

Comment: I added edit to original post.

Answer (score 0):

According to your updated, it sounds like you had installed the `xgboost` wheel file successfully on Azure ML, but got an issue "ImportError: No module named xgboost" when using it.

As reference, there are two solutions which you can resolve the issue.

1. If you got the `xgboost` installed path from the result of installation via `pip.main` method, you can try to add the code as below to append the library path dynamically.

   ```
   import os
   import sys
   sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), '<the installed path of xgboost>'))
   ```
2. Try to create a clean Python virtual environment via `virtualenv`, and do `pip install xgboost` or `pip install xgboost.whl` to get the dependencies into your site-packages directory on the new python virtual environment. And zipped the site-packages folder and uploaded as the Zip file, then included the reference to the site-packages directory and successfully imported the required items.

Hope it helps.

---

Update:

Try to download the `xgboost` wheel file and its dependencies from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#xgboost), and decompress them to package the files in the wheel path like `xgboost-0.6.data` as a zip file to upload & use it as the script bundle.

Comment: Hello.
Thank you for your reply. I've now tried both approaches and I haven't been able to make it work.
I still get the import errors.

Comment: Hello.
I've tried that was my original approach as well and the error I got was:
%1 is not a valid Win32 application\r\nProcess returned with non-zero exit code 1
Which is very strange since my python installation and package should have the correct version and type(see image in original post).